# The number 1 evaluates inside HoldForm sometimes

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold

If I run the following code:

```
Do[
 Print["*** ", HoldForm[x] /. x -> a, " ***"];
 Print["Replace: ", (HoldForm[x] /. x -> a) /. {n1 -> 1, n2 -> 2, n3 -> 3}];
 Print["FullForm: ", FullForm[a]];
 , {a, {n1 n2, -n1 n2, n1 n2 n3}}
 ]
```

I get

```
    *** n1 n2 ***
    Replace: 1 x 2
    FullForm: Times[n1,n2]
    *** -n1 n2 ***
    Replace: -2
    FullForm: Times[-1,n1,n2]
    *** n1 n2 n3 ***
    Replace: 2 x 3
    FullForm: Times[n1,n2,n3]
```

I kind of understand what is going on, but I would like the output in the second case to be `-1 x 2` and in the third case `1 x 2 x 3`. How do I do that?

Comment: Because $1$ is an identity element for multiplication, it gets removed at once in `Times[]`. (Similarly, $0$ is quickly removed in `Plus[]`.) Perhaps you want something like `Inactivate[Times[1, 2, 3], Times]`?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I need to block `1`, not `Times`, and `Inactivate[1]` is just the same as `1`. However, your solution inspired me to find a solution of my own, which I will post now.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to write the substitution rule as

```
{n1 -> HoldForm[1], n2 -> 2, n3 -> 3}
```

If later one wants the expression evaluated, it will be enough to use `HoldForm[]` twice.